# process works without ampersand but doesn't work with ampersand

Tags: php, daemon

I wrote a small script to run as a daemon, everything seems to work when I run the command in unix:

```
php script.php
```

everything seems to work correctly, when I terminate that script and us the following, de script isn't running in the background:

```
php script.php &
```

What am I doing wrong? could it be a server problem or a script problem?

Comment: Maybe your script needs input from stdin?

Comment: no it doesn't,it's just a test file that writes a string in a log file

Comment: In-depth discussion on php scripts as daemons: [see this stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036654/run-php-script-as-daemon-process).

Answer (score 1):

even if php doesn't look like it's going to write output, it does prepare itself to write headers at the very least.  that behavior can be suppressed by using the `-q` option with php.

```
php -q script.php >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

should get you where you need to be.

if you want to see whether or not php really ouputs anything, try

```
php -q script.php >/tmp/script.log 2>&1 &
```

Then see if /tmp/script.log is still 0 bytes after the script has run.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
php script.php  > /dev/null 2>&1 &

Comment: this is not working either

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Clarify what you mean by not working. Also what happens when you just execute the script using php script.php? Do you see any output?

Comment: the output I get when I run it with an ampersand is: 

     [1] 24817

Comment: ...which means its this shell session's *first* job sent to the background and its `pid` is 24817.  Sounds right, doesn't it?  (Don't you get your prompt back?  Have you checked `ps aux | grep php` for the script running in background?)